# Why tabs and fragments not showing up?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-tabs

For some reason my Tabs are not showing up.
My player home activity should display two tabs naming *Profile* and *Teams* but it is not showing anything. And also not showing any error.

**`OnCreate` Player home Activity**

```
mainAppToolBar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mainAppBar);
    setSupportActionBar(mainAppToolBar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Player Home");

    playerTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.playerMainTabs);
    playerViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.playerMainTabPager);

    playerSectionPageAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    playerViewPager.setAdapter(playerSectionPageAdapter);
    playerTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(playerViewPager);
```

**Code for Section Page Adapter**

```
public class SectionPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public SectionPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
            return profileFragment;
        case 1:
            TeamFragment teamFragment = new TeamFragment();
            return teamFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return 2;}
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Profile";
        case 1:
            return "Teams";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}}
```

Please help.

Comment: please post your layout file of PlayerHomeActivity

Comment: Nemsis i cant find the layout file, pls post it in question

Comment: @darwin Could you please [see here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fOSYnkWqlvp87pm87yvHFoZ5P4mJQDNUgQ43FhaJXfk/edit?usp=sharing)  I can't post it in the question as it is showing message your question is mostly code.

Comment: i think the issue is with <include layout="@layout/app_bar_layout"
           android:id="@+id/mainAppBar" />, try removing those lines and check its working or not

Comment: @darwin Tried, still not working. The crazy thing is  I checked my code with another working app in which I used tabs and there is no problem I can identify by comparing both.

Comment: can u try this tutorial,its well explained https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: @darwin found the problem, I was missing one "s" in the spelling of my SectionPagerAdapter class. Stupid one.LOL. Thanks for your help

Comment: great, I'm glad you found it

Answer (score 0):

`getCount()` is overriden, but I don't see that `getPageTitle` is. I think you're missing that `@override`.

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() { return 2;}

    @Override - add this
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Profile";
            case 1:
                return "Teams";
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }}
```

Comment: Actual problem was, I did spelling mistake while creating the sectionpagerAdapter class. By the way, thank you for pointing `@override` however, it was not required to run the code but it is always good practice to make `override` automatically it.